Connecting an app to Meta Business Manager - whose account to use: my company's or the clients?
I work for an online marketing company that also builds and rents websites for our clients. Clients pay us a monthly subscription, but the websites are legally our property.
Recently, some of our clients requested to have their customers sign into their woocommerce shops via their Facebook account. It's my first time using Facebook Developer platform and I'm confused.
I need to go through a business verification and log into a Meta Business Manager account. Can I use my company's profile? We rent websites to multiple businesses and I wonder if I can manage all their apps from our account, or if every business should be verified on its own. Is there any danger of our company account being banned or blocked if I use it to manage the apps for our clients?
I don't know if all of our clients have Meta Business Manager accounts and it would be much easier to manage all apps from one place. However, me and my boss aren't sure if we can verify apps connected to outside domains from our Meta Business Manager account. We have Facebook campaigns going and I don't want to mess them up.

You should have each client have their own Facebook account and Meta Business Manager Account. They will need to create it and add you as admin.
You can also create it with your personal account and add the client as admin to the account.
Having separate accounts will protect your account and other clients from being affected if the client's account gets banned for some reason.

Thank you for your answer TimberWebDesign! If I could ask a follow-up question - do I understand correctly that if I don't set up the app correctly, then I can cause a ban to the "whole" facebook account (facebook profile and Meta uBusiness Manager) or only the developer platform? Or did you mean a ban caused by something not related to my app?

No, your account/app shouldn’t be banned because you set it up incorrectly. They normally only ban a Business Manager if you don’t (or they think you don't) follow their policies. It shouldn’t extend to the FB profile unless you are doing something really shady.
